# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un item de un JSONArray?

Tags: java, json

`JSON` obtenido en response:

```
[{"codigo":"10","nombre":"Ejemplo"}]
```

Necesitaría obtener solo la cadena de texto `Ejemplo` para pasarlo a un `TextView`. De momento solo tengo el `array`.

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor del campo `nombre` de la respuesta `JSON`?

Comment: En [éste enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java) está lo que buscas.

Comment: Obtienes un arreglo de elementos, así que obtén el primer elemento del arreglo, y de él obtén el campo que necesitas.

Comment: No había visto tu pregunta hasta el día de hoy, agregué respuesta donde muestro como obtener los valores del objecto dentro de un JSONArray @luDev

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
JsonObject objeto = json.getJsonObject(posicionDeElemento);
String nombre = objeto.getString("nombre");
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma adecuada es usar las clases `JSONArray` y `JSONObject` :

Suponiendo que tu variable `response` contiene la respuesta:

```
 [{"codigo":"10","nombre":"Ejemplo"}]
```

Obtenemos el valor del array y su primer objeto (indice 0):

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject objeto = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
```

a partir del `JSONObject` , puedes obtener los valores del objeto mediante su nombre:

```
String valorCodigo = objeto.getString("codigo"); //obtiene valor 10
String valorNombre = objeto.getString("nombre"); //obtiene valor Ejemplo
```

Comment: Jorge en relación a tu respuesta si quiero obtener los valores de 2 objetos como recorro ese JSONObject objeto = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);.Saludos

Answer (score 0):

tomando nuevamente esta pregunta, como hacer para obtener un listado de datos dentro de ese mismo json. ejemplo:

```
[{"codigo":"10","nombre":"Ejemplo","listadoActividades":{"nombre":"Resolver","numeroActividad":"2","actividadRealizada":"1","Usuarios":{"nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Perez","codigousuario":"123"}}}]
```